# Set height UILabel to 0

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

Is there anyway to set the height of a UILabel programmatically? I've added a bunch of constraints to my .Xib files so every other label is dependent upon the one above or below it for it's positioning. It'd make my life so much easier if I could just use:

```
nameLabel.height = 0
```

My .Xib looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried hiding it through the hidden property?

Comment: Hiding works but my labels below it don't move up the 22 pixels I want them to then.

Comment: You can create a NSLayoutConstraint property and init the constraint for the height attribute of your label. Then when you want to hide the label, set the `constraint.constant value = 0`, call `self.view.layoutIfNeeded();` Note: for the constraint, add the relation item to `nil` and the relating attribute value to `NotAnAttribute` this tells the constraint it's height value isn't related to any other views.

Comment: Thanks - this what I've done for now. Seems like a awful lot work though. Was expecting something easier to do the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

plz take the IBoutlet of constraint height and set the height you want[image]

Comment: This works! It's more work than I want it to be though :(

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var frame: CGRect = nameLabel.frame
frame.size.height = height
nameLabel.frame = frame
```

Answer (score 0):

Write this line :

```
constLblHeight.constant = 0;

//Below image step
//Step 1: Add Constraint in label height
//Step 2: Create object of label height constraint (constLblHeight)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you empty the label its height will be zero.

```
nameLabel.text = ""
```

Even no need to hide it.