# how draw button story board?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

[image]

[image]

[image]

i want to button width = 1

but current image red button : Gray button

2 : 1 how draw buttons -> 1 : 1

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve? that both buttons will have the same width and height ?

Comment: plz see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37582155/set-height-uilabel-to-0/37582462#37582462

Answer (score 1):

- First delete all constrains from view controller
- Drag Red button from left blue line to center blue line
- Drag Gray button from Right blue line to center blue line
- create constrains for left button to View leading and top space
- create constrains for Right button to View trailing and top space
- create constrains for red button to gray button horizontal space
- now update frames then check

Answer (score 1):

i don't really know what you want, but if you want two buttons like this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxVNW.png),here is the answer.
add constraints to left button like this [left button constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0fd0.png)

all you need to do is add margin between two buttons and make them equal width.

sorry i cant post more than 2 links.

Answer (score 1):

if you want height and width equal for both items use these constants :-
[image]

Comment: hey if you find the answer helpful don't forget to mark it right  : )

Answer (score 1):

Use this constraints

1. Button1(left button) ie.  add [left,bottom,horizontal space to right button2,equal height and width to button2 by(draging button1 one towards button2)]
2. Button 2(right): add [right,and bottom constraint]
3. update frame is any warning by selecting buttons constraint issue

[image: Storyboard Image]