# Auto layout in iOS

Tags: autolayout

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zqcV.png)

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTsnu.png)

In my iPad app, on a `View controller` an `image view` and `textview` are present.

Sometimes the image is null so no need to show image in that case (in UI the `textview` becomes bigger and come in the place of `image view` also).

For this what can I do?

Please help me.

Comment: Which constraints you used for your view ??

Comment: ben what you need . are you what UI the text view not become bigger?

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @balkaran singh - yes i need bigger text view if no image.

Comment: @Ben Can you please share the pictures of your constraint on the view controller ?

Comment: @j. Koush - edited my question please see the image.

Comment: @Ben what are the changes in your code? because the auto layout is fine.

Comment: but my question is how i make textview bigger if no image data in image view. i am new in app iOS development. any code i need to write to remove image view. and make the textview bigger.

Comment: @Ben check the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

plz create a  outlet  of imageheight

like this
[Set height UILabel to 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37582155/set-height-uilabel-to-0/37582462#37582462)

IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *imageheightCont;

when you want image hidden set

**imageheightCont.constant = 0;**